# Kivy labels not updating unless function is called from a button

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a program. A variable is in a text document, and receiving the variable is not the issue.

I want the label to update whenever getTotalPair is called. Right now, it will only update if it is directly called from a button.

Screen Class:

```
class Generate(Screen):
def getTotalPair(self):
    f = open('temp.txt', 'r')
    totalvalue = f.read()
    f.close()
    self.ids.labelID.text = '{}'.format(totalvalue)
```

MainApp Function: (getTotalPair)

```
def GENERATE(self):
    self.sm.current = 'generate'
    p = Generate()
    threading.Thread(target=p.getTotalPair()).start()
```

Button that calls the Generate Screen:

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
text: 'Generate Now'
pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
on_press: root.createQR()
on_release: app.GENERATE()
```

Possible fixes: I have removed the thread and added this as well as @mainthread to getTotalPair()

```
Clock.schedule_once(XRPqr().getTotalPair, 1)
```

**NOW**, if I create a button that directly calls getTotalPair() it will work as I want, the label in Generate will be updated. SO This is not a problem of any simple mistake, I believe it is something deeper that I obviously don't understand.

I have tried everything. This is a fundamental part of my project. The kivy discord is not much help, they am probably creating new Generate instances, which I do not fully understand.

Comment: It is not clear what your desired behavior is. What do you want your code to do?

Comment: I want the label to successfully change whenever the getTotalPair function is called

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
threading.Thread(target=p.getTotalPair()).start()
```

is calling `p.getTotalPair()` and assigning its return as the `target`. That return is `None`, so that thread does nothing. Try changing it to:

```
threading.Thread(target=p.getTotalPair).start()
```

Notice the removed `()`.